# How to search a html file for substring in PHP?

Tags: php, substring

I have this script to open a web page and count every line with an `img` tag.  However, it is not working. Could help me to find out the problem with the script? This array should hold info of every line but it is giving about only 1 line of its choice.

```
<?php
$a = 'www.exaple.com/examplepage.html'; //page i want to search
$b = fopens($a , "r"); //to open the page for viewing source
$line = array("0" => "false"); //to keep record of lines with img tag we dont have  line 0 so dont worry
$x = 0; //varialble to hold no. of lines
while(!feof($b)) {   //search every line of file upto the end
    $x = $x+1; //update line every it loops
    $pos = strrpos(fgets($b) ,"<img"); //seach for the img tag
    if($pos === false) { $line = array($x , "false"); } //keep record of line without img tag as fasle
    else { $line = array($x , "true"); } //keep record of line with img tag as true
}
print_r($line);
fclose($b);
?>
```

Comment: Alright. First issue; `$a` isn't enclosed in quotes, and it doesn't end in a semicolon. You'd want `$a = 'www.example.com/examplepage.html';`

Comment: Secondly, the proper way to re-ask your question is to edit your first question (since this is the same question, only with code) and flag your question to be reopened.

Comment: can you find more problems because it is not my real code i wrote in a bit hurry so forgot to add quotes and end the statement but its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this: `$line = array($x , "true");`
You are assigning a new value to `$line`, not pushing the value into the array.

Instead you should do either of this:

```
$line[$x] = "true" // or false, whatever
```